# Script to make schedule tasks on Windows with Admin credentials

Tags: passwords, password-management

I have a written a script (in R)

```
cmd = paste0("schtasks /create /sc WEEKLY /d MON /tn ",task," /tr ",comm," /st 12:51")
system(command = cmd)
```

Where `task` is the name of the task and `comm` is the location of `R` and the script. This works and the script is executed. However I have some scripts where I would like to pass my credentials.

Essentially this is just adding `/RU *** /RP ***` to `cmd`, however I don't think storing my username and password is a good idea in a shared file.

Is there a way to encrypt the credentials or maybe another alternative?

Comment: Probably better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you need elevated permissions to run the task on the system, or do you need to access another system?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing it in R, you can do it in Powershell and save the credentials as a secure string.  That solves the problem of it being human-readable, but the credentials used to create it are still available (which is not a good security practice).  More info on that is available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160822030847/http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2007/02/16/106518.aspx).    Otherwise you can do this in Powershell and use [get-credential](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-5.1), which prompts you to enter the appropriate credentials.  (That's a lot more secure way to handle that, although it comes with the "bother" of entering your ID and password)

Comment: The credentials would still be in the script and Secure-String is only used to prevent attacks against strings in memory. A schedule task is not going to work with get-credential due to the prompt

Comment: This might be a simple (read: not ideal) suggestion, but you could use an algorithm to encrypt these fields and store these encrypted fields in, say, a locked file, in a way that is also not human readable. Then, implement a way to decrypt this input into the script and read the input from the stored location into a variable you can then use and discard from memory after. This might allow you to automate the process but likewise, this isn't 100% secure.